# Метод onConfigurationChanged() срабатывает 3 раза, и только 1-й раз с правильным значением

Tags: android, android-themes

Проблема: когда я меняю системную тему на ночную, то метод onConfigurationChanged срабатывает 3 раза (один из них для темы), но тема ночная только в первом из трёх, а остальные содержат инфу что тема - DAY. Соответственно у меня метод который дергаетсядалее, берет в значение сначала NIGHT, а потом два раза DAY. Получается не могу прокинуть нормально значение и поменять состояние того что нужно.

То есть:

-При смене темы на темную, приходят значения по очереди: темная, светлая, светлая (информация о переключении смены на темную перекрывается двумя последующими срабатываниями метода onConfigurationChanged).

-При смене темы на светлую - метод срабатывает со значениями: светлая, светлая, светлая.

В Манифесте:

```
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|fontScale|uiMode"
```

Логи:

```
    //смена системной темы на ночную:
    2021-11-25 16:53:45/com.its.myapp.debug D/MainAct LOGS: onConfigurationChanged: SYSTEM_THEME = NIGHT
    2021-11-25 16:53:45/com.its.myapp.debug D/MainAct LOGS: onConfigurationChanged: SYSTEM_THEME = DAY
    2021-11-25 16:53:45/com.its.myapp.debug D/MainAct LOGS: onConfigurationChanged: SYSTEM_THEME = DAY

    //смена системной темы на дневную:
    2021-11-25 16:53:48/com.its.myapp.debug D/MainAct LOGS: onConfigurationChanged: SYSTEM_THEME = DAY
    2021-11-25 16:53:48/com.its.myapp.debug D/MainAct LOGS: onConfigurationChanged: SYSTEM_THEME = DAY
    2021-11-25 16:53:48/com.its.myapp.debug D/MainAct LOGS: onConfigurationChanged: SYSTEM_THEME = DAY
```

Код:

```
override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
        var isSystemNightMode = newConfig.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK
        when (isSystemNightMode) {
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "onConfigurationChanged: SYSTEM_THEME = NIGHT")
            }
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "onConfigurationChanged: SYSTEM_THEME = DAY")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: А где сам код? Логов мало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единственный вариант что мне помог в данной ситуации - в конце срабатывания каждого onConfigurationChange() запускать функцию, спрашивающую систему "а действительно ли тема та, что указана в onConfigurationChanged()?"

Возможно, это - костыль, но всё работает.

Я написал так (функция внизу):

```
override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
        var isSystemNightMode = newConfig.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK
        when (isSystemNightMode) {
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "onConfigurationChanged: SYSTEM_THEME = DAY")
                getSystemTheme()
            }
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "onConfigurationChanged: SYSTEM_THEME = NIGHT")
                getSystemTheme()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getSystemTheme() {
        when (resources.configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) {
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "getSystemTheme: SYSTEM_THEME = DAY")
                // далее кастомные функции при дневной теме
            }
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "getSystemTheme: SYSTEM_THEME = NIGHT")
                // далее кастомные функции при ночной теме
            }
        }
    }
```